# Iphone SDK: move and rotate to touch

Tags: iphone, image, rotation, touch, move

I have an image of a fish - If the user touches the screen I want the fish to "look" at the touched point and move there. If the touch has been moved i want the fish constantly following the touch.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

would be something like this:

```
- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    UITouch *tap = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint pointToMove = [tap locationInView:self.view];

    CGFloat xdiff = pointToMove.x-myFish.center.x;
    CGFloat ydiff = pointToMove.y-myFish.center.y;

    if (!CGRectContainsPoint(myFish.frame, pointToMove)) {
        CGFloat angle = 0;
        if (xdiff) {
            if (xdiff>0) {
                angle = atanf(ydiff/xdiff);
            } else {
                angle = M_PI + atanf(ydiff/xdiff);
            }
        }
        [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
        [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.3f];
        [UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState:YES];
        [UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveLinear];        
        myFish.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(angle);
        [UIView commitAnimations];
    } 

    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:1.0f];
    [UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState:YES];
    [UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveLinear];    
    myFish.center = pointToMove;
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

and you probably want to implement these too:

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
```

**EDIT:** updated code, now the rotation is done in a separate animation, so that the fish rotates faster than he swims.

Comment: to let the fish "look" to your finger you would check if the touch is right or left from the current fish position and then replace the image with another one

Comment: i did that before, but i don't want to replace the image - i want to  be able to rotate the image 360 degrees.

Comment: this is currently not completely correct but you will get an insight how this could be done. Something with my degrees calculation is not right, but I cannot figure it out.

Comment: Thank you, the "Move to Point" method works really well the degrees are behaving really strange though :S

Comment: @phix23 thanks for the completion works perfectly but the transform should be applied inside the UIView animation, then the rotation will be smooth and correct. Please edit it to keep your name displayed as a co-solver.

Comment: haha! :D :D it works now! tnx phix23 i'l go and + you up a bit ;)