# Iphone: Appear and allow user interactions on the UIImage

Tags: iphone, camera, uiimage

How could i build an application that first in a blank UIView, then allow users to take a picture using camera, the picture will then appear on the UiView which users can drag and move the image around.

Here is my code that i have so far,

```
-(IBAction) getPhoto:(id) sender {
    UIImagePickerController * picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    picker.delegate = self;

    if((UIButton *) sender == choosePhotoBtn) {
        picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeSavedPhotosAlbum;
    } else {
        picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
        savebutton.hidden=NO;
    }

    [self presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];
}
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {
    [picker dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    imageView.image = [info objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"];
}

-(void)imageSavedToPhotosAlbum:(UIImage *)image didFinishSavingWithError:(NSError *)error contextInfo:(void *)contextInfo {
    NSString *message; NSString *title; 
    if (!error) {
        title = NSLocalizedString(@"Image Saved Successfully!", @"");
        message = NSLocalizedString(@"Tap Library and select this image.", @"");
    }

 else { title = NSLocalizedString(@"SaveFailedTitle", @""); message = [error description];
 } UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:title 
                                                   message:message delegate:nil
                                         cancelButtonTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"OK", @"") otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert show]; [alert release];
    [message release]; [title release];}

-(IBAction) saveImage:(id)sender{
    UIImage *img = imageView.image;
    UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(img, self, @selector(imageSavedToPhotosAlbum: didFinishSavingWithError: contextInfo:), nil);
}
```

Also is there any good tutorial on photo modification in Xcode?

Many Thanks.

Comment: Don't you think that you are asking to build whole app from the same question? Try to implement something first.

Comment: I have edited the questions. I just know how to initiate the camera and and place it on a UIImage, but i have no idea how to drag this picture around. Many Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take the help of uitouchmoved class and using the same you can move around the image in the uiview easily.See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5653682/iphone-sdk-move-and-rotate-to-touch).